# Using Android Beam less API level 14

Tags: android

So, that's my problem, I wanna have one Activity to work on all of the API level I support on my Activity (from API level 8 to current API level).

My problem is that if I want to use Android Beam I need my Activity to implement

**`NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback`** 
and 
**`NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback`**
 but I cannot make it work if the SDK level is below 14.

Does anyone know if I can do something else to make it work like for example youtube application does or do I need to have two different applications, one for Android less API 14 and another one for Android API 14?

Comment: Do you mean you want Android Beam to work on all devices or you want to use the same activity on all devices and disable Beam functionality on those that do not support it?

Comment: The second one. I want to use the same Activity on all devices and disable Beam functionality on those that do not support it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the interface implementation directly in your activity.

Instead, check the SDK level and set the callback manually if you are above SDK14

e.g:

```
private class myCallback implements NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback {

    @Override
    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent nfcEvent) {
        // Your callback code
        ...
    }
}

MyNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(new myCallback, activity, activities);
```

Comment: That is what I finally did. I think this is the best solution for what I wanted. I tried on an Android device without NFC, another with NFC but API level less than 14, and another device with API Level 14 and it is working the way it has to on every devices. Thanks a lot!